# How to fix warning CA2226 in a C++/CLI application?

Tags: c++-cli, fxcop

I have a C++/CLI class definition where I'm trying to get Equality testing to be Value based rahter than Reference (similar to the behavior of String).  The following definitions work:

```
namespace MyCode
{
 public ref class MyClass
 {
 public:
  MyClass();
  bool operator==(MyClass^ obj) { return Equals(obj); }
  bool operator!=(MyClass^ obj) { return !Equals(obj); }
  virtual bool Equals(MyClass^ obj);
  virtual bool Equals(System::Object^ obj) override;
  virtual int GetHashCode() override;
 };
}
```

However, my company is now requiring (and rightly so) that all code needs to conform to the Code Analysis rules.  Code analysis consistently reports two warnings on the above class:

```
CA2226 : Microsoft.Usage : Since ''MyClass'' redefines operator '==', it should also redefine operator '!='.
CA2226 : Microsoft.Usage : Since ''MyClass'' redefines operator '!=', it should also redefine operator '=='.
```

The Microsoft documentation on warning CA2226 makes it clear that this is an important warning and should not be suppressed - but what else can I do?

I'm looking for a way (if possible) to 'fix' the code in order to remove this warning.  Is that possible, or do I just need to suppress it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a .NET implementation detail.  Having instance operator overloads is a C++ feature, the code analyzer chokes on it.  The .NET way is to have operator overloads as static functions.  Notably C# requires this.  Solve your problem similar to this:

```
  static bool operator==(MyClass^ lhs, MyClass^ rhs) { return lhs->Equals(rhs); }
  static bool operator!=(MyClass^ lhs, MyClass^ rhs) { return !lhs->Equals(rhs); }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I find it odd that the compiler and analyzer both allow the C++ instance operators when C# does not.  I would expect one or the other to complain that instance operators are not allowed on ref classes.

Answer (score 2):

For a `ref class`, you're supposed to implement `operator==(MyClass^ left, MyClass^ right)` as a static member function, this is the one other .NET languages will find.

Your current implementation defines `operator==(MyClass%, MyClass^ right)` instead, which is unusual.

Note that you can't rely on `left != nullptr`, you need to test `ReferenceEquals(left, nullptr)`.