# C++/CLI overloaded operator is not accessed via C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli, operator-overloading

I've the following C++/CLI class:

```
 public ref class MyClass
    {
    public:
        int val;
        bool operator==(MyClass^ other)
        {
            return this->val == other->val;
        }

        bool Equals(MyClass^ other)
        {
            return this == other;
        }
    };
```

When I try to verify from C# whether two instances of `MyClass` are equal I get a wrong result:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass();
MyClass b = new MyClass();

//equal1 is false since the operator is not called
bool equal1 = a == b;
//equal2 is true since the comparison operator is called from within C++\CLI
bool equal2 = a.Equals(b);
```

What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix warning CA2226 in a C++/CLI application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589426/how-to-fix-warning-ca2226-in-a-c-cli-application)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `==` operator you are overloading is not accessible in C# and the line `bool equal1 = a == b` compares `a` and `b` by reference.

Binary operators are overriden by static methods in C# and you need to provide this operator instead:

```
static bool operator==(MyClass^ a, MyClass^ b)
{
  return a->val == b->val;
}
```

When overriding `==` you should also override `!=`. In C# this is actually enforced by the compiler.

Comment: Note that for value types, you should use the handle syntax for the parameters as well.